# problem with condition statement despite using right operator

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean, conditional-statements

I wrote this script to create a specific variable that takes different values according to the number of reports. Count of Report is an integer column.

```
no_audit = df_bei_index['Count of Report'] == 0 
few_audit = df_bei_index['Count of Report'] > 0 & df_bei_index['Count of Report'] < 30

col_list = ['Policy Index (ELEVATE)_score', 'Transparency Score']

for col in col_list:
        df_bei_index[col+'_corrected'] = np.where(m1, df_bei_index['PDI_Average'], np.where( 
                                                  m2, df_bei_index[col]*0.05 + df_bei_index['PDI_Average']*0.95
                                                  , df_bei_index[col]))
```

yet, when I run it, I get the following mistake:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-42-6fe73dad7759> in <module>()
>      41 no_audit = df_bei_index['Count of Report'] == 0
>      42 df_bei_index
> ---> 43 few_audit = df_bei_index[(df_bei_index['Count of Report'] > 0 & df_bei_index['Count of Report'] < 30)]
>      44 
>      45 
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
> __nonzero__(self)    1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "    1575                          "Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
> -> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))    1577     1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__
> 
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I looked around and this error comes up when you use 'and' or 'or' instead of '&' or '|', but clearly this is not my case.

What is wrong the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `m2` with adding `()`

```
m1= df_bei_index['Count of Report'] == 0 
m2= (df_bei_index['Count of Report'] > 0) & (df_bei_index['Count of Report'] < 30)
```